# How to take all elements after index 3?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I need to implement a menu in the header: when a user adds a menu item in the HTML file and there are more than 3 of them, an ellipsis appears on hover, which pops up a popup with menu items that do not fit. That is, the first 3 menu items are static in the header, and the rest that are added go to the popup.
Now I have implemented in my code that when there are more than 3 menu items, an ellipsis appears. How can I add menu items to popup that are added to html?

```js
const headerMenu = document.querySelector(".header-menu__list");
const headerMenuLi = document.querySelectorAll(".header-menu__list li");
const headerMenuToArray = Array.from(headerMenuLi);
const ellipsisLi = document.createElement("li");
ellipsisLi.classList.add("open-sub__menu");
const ellipsisA = document.createElement("a");
ellipsisA.innerHTML = "<span>...</span>";
const subMenu = document.createElement("ul");
subMenu.classList.add("header-sub__menu");
ellipsisLi.appendChild(ellipsisA);
ellipsisLi.appendChild(subMenu);



const addEllipsis = (arr) => {
  if (arr.length > 3) {
    headerMenu.children[2].after(ellipsisLi);

  }
};

addEllipsis(headerMenuToArray);
```

```css
.header-sub__menu {
  background: #171a21 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 120%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 250px;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.open-sub__menu:hover .header-sub__menu {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<ul class="header-menu__list">
  <li><a href="">Find events</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Create an event</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Help</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: i need to take all items after index 3. User can add 10 new items